# In my PhpStorm 2021.1.4 I can not find JetBrains Gateway?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-gateway

With PhpStorm 2021.1.4 ( Build #PS-211.7628.25, built on June 30, 2021 ) I
need to debug my remote PHP project on Ubuntu/Digital Ocean.

Searching on the internet I found “JetBrains Gateway” referenced as decision of this issue: https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/11/29/introducing-remote-development-for-jetbrains-ides/

But on my IDE I did not find how to open dialog like :

[image]

Is it some additional plugin or a separate version of PhpStorm? How can I check it ?

Comment: The article you links says it's introduced with 2021.3 and you have 2021.1.

Comment: You need a newer IDE version (just as **Álvaro González** said) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/. Can also try the JetBrains Gateway Standalone app -- https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/